# Install VMware on Ubuntu 18.10 -- Build environment error

Tags: vmware

I did the basic install, but when I run it, I get:

```
Build environment error! A required application is missing and modconfig cannot continue. xzCheck the log for more details.
```

What does that mean and what should I do?

Answer (score 14):

Run the following commands before/after installing vmware:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
sudo apt-get install make
sudo apt-get update
```

Let me know if you have any other errors we will sort it out.

Comment: Installing `gcc` and `make` solved this exact error for me when installing VMware Workstation 15 on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Had this issue on Ubuntu 20.04 and Vmware complained about `gcc` not being installed, but it forgot to mention `make`. Thx.

Comment: Solved for me too.

Answer (score 7):

As suggested in https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1002411

```
vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

worked on kubuntu 18.04 with VMware Workstation Player 15.5.0

Installing `gcc` and `make` did not solve the error, or at least were not sufficient.

Comment: solved it for me on Ubuntu 20.04 together with installing gcc and make.

Comment: Thanks, this also worked for me (22.04.3 LTS)